# How to interpolate in MatLab

Tags: matlab

I have a 1x1 Matrix of points which specifies speed of a drive with respect to time. This speed changes throughout the operation; which means that the difference between two points is changing.

To give you an example: `M = [1; 2; 3; 5; 7; 9; 11; 15; 19]`. 
(Only that this is a 892x1 matrix)

I want to make this matrix twice as long (so changing the relative speed per timestep), while retaining the way the speeds change. Eg: `M' = [1; 1.5; 2; 2.5; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7; 8; 9; 10; 11; 13; 15; 17; 19].`

Is there an easy way to do this in MatLab?

So far I have tried `upsampling` (which fills the time step with zeros); `interp` (which fills it with low-pass interpolation.

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure if you need is `interpolation`...sounds more like `shifting`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
M = [1; 2; 3; 5; 7; 9; 11; 15; 19];

% create new time, with twice as many sampling times
t_new = linspace(1, numel(M), 2*numel(M)-1);

% interpolate
Mt = interp1(M, t_new),
```

Note that `interp1`  also accepts additional arguments, like `spline` or `pchip` that allow you to specfify what interpolation kernel to use. Read `help interp1` for more information.

Alternatively, you can use something like

```
pp = spline(t, M);    % creates a cubic-splines interpolator
Mt = ppval(pp, t_new) % to evaluate M at all new times t_new
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much!! I had been trying different ways for 3 hours now.

Comment: @Acorbe: User Amro has created a [user-script for Matlab syntax highlighting](https://github.com/amroamroamro/prettify-matlab/raw/master/js/prettify-matlab.user.js) on SO, making those `//` unnecessary.

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis, really sorry. I didn't know. I roll back the changes.

Comment: @Acorbe: Oh you can leave them in, no worries. They're still useful for passers-by that don't have the user script installed.