# Extracting data points from a plot on a finer scale

Tags: matlab

I want to extract data from a plotted graph I have in matlab. As such, I did the following:

```
f = openfig('spline.fig');
xdata = get(gco, 'xdata');
ydata = get(gco, 'ydata');
```

This does give me the data points of `x` and `y` respectively, but with a step of `0.5` between each points (*e.g* 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5...). I was hoping to get finer data points than that (*e.g* 1, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4...), and the corresponding y-coordinates to these x-coordinates. How can I do this?

Comment: If you want finer points, I'd suggest [interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation). There are numerous questions regarding this (_e.g_ [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13700328/how-to-interpolate-in-matlab)).

Comment: Well, the easiest way is to generate the figure with the desired steps you want. Otherwise you will have to interpolate. In this case, take a look for the lagrange interpolation.

Comment: I guess the question is: when plotting Data, is xData/yData equal to x,y in plot(x,y)? Well, I dont know this and would be interested in an answer too...

Comment: hey Werner,What do u mean by generate the fig with the desired steps i want?

Comment: not reall, for the x data and y data, i only have a set of 10 x and y data. Somehow, matlab helps to break the x into even smaller steps (1, 1.5,2,2.5...),but what i really want is even smaller steps like (1, 1.1,1.2...)

Comment: So yes Lucius, xData/yData gets you the exact x,y data used in plot(x,y)!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way you got your `ydata` didn't work for me, I would use:

```
open testfigure.fig 
D = get(gca, 'Children');
ydata = get(D, 'YData');
```

The `ydata` I obtained contains the original y-data used to plot the figure.

Now, if you need a finer resolution in the data you will have to interpolate that yourself. 
Here's short example of how to interpolate this `ydata` to a resolution of 0.1:

1. Define new x values xi to find y values for

   ```
   xi = 0:0.1:10;
   ```
2. Interpolate `ydata` to find new `yi` values at `xi`:

   ```
   yi = interp1(xdata, ydata, xi); %// Using the default "linear"
   ```

You should read up on the kind of method you want to use (*e.g.* [nearest neighbour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest-neighbor_interpolation), [spline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_interpolation)), this depends on your data and requirements.

Comment: thanks,Fraukje! Would u mind telling me where i can find info on interpolating in regards to my problem?or how should i go about it? Thanks!

Comment: should i use spline interpolation? does matlab have this?

Comment: If you are unfamiliar with this I would suggest looking into the `interp1` function see (http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html) and look at some examples

Comment: This can handle spline interpolations, or you can use the function `spline`.

Comment: the function spline can only generate a spline fit graph? is this the function you are saying?

Comment: The function `spline` interpolates data in a cubic way. See the Matlab Documentation Centre for more info >> http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/spline.html?searchHighlight=spline

Comment: @Fraukje You should show the OP an example of interpolation with `interp1` to make your answer complete (as it currently stands, you're mostly repeating what has been said in the comments)

Comment: @Fraukje Great! That deserves a +1. I've taken the liberty to tidy your answer up a bit (feel free to roll back my changes if you don't like them, of course).

Comment: @EitanT Thanks a lot. I am just getting the hang of answering questions, so I'm happy with your comments really!

Comment: Thanks Fraukje and EitanT. I would probably need to use spline. Does the short example you provided works for spline?

Comment: I recommend using `interp1(xdata,ydata,xi,'spline')` for that. It is the same as using `spline` but it will give you the opportunity to test other methods as well.

Comment: yea it helped alot, just one last question, does doing    interp1(xdata,ydata,xi,'spline') means that the graph is first best fitted into a spline graph before it is interpolated? because when the graph is first plotted, it is plotted by means of straight lines between each points, which makes the whole graph and result inaccurate

Comment: Spline assumes that the data behaves as a polynomial of some form, so if you interpolate your data first with spline and then plot it the 'straight lines' will have disappeared. Be cautious with this though, because this is an assumption which not always holds for each kind of data. And if the resolution of the data is really low you might consider remeasuring with a higher sample frequency instead of interpolating.

Comment: ok.Thanks.I think i have a better idea of stuff and it did help my queation. so thanks! just want to ask though, what do u mean by resolution of data, and what do u mean measuring with a higher sample frequency?

Comment: @BenjaminAlonsoTan This means you'll have to increase the number of samples with actual data instead of using interpolation methods to "guess" what would be the values between samples.